# Running ajax request in javascript synchronously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having this problem with my code. I have a function performing AJAX call and bringing up the interface and that AJAX is separated in a different function. I am calling it in somewhere and some code follows it. Here is an example :

```
function doAjaxStuff(){
//do something
}

function anotherFunction(){
doAjaxStuff();
//proceed with further code
}
```

(The function `anotherFunction` is getting called from `$(document).ready`)

As the further code is completely dependent upon the things I'm loading, like I'm trying to accessing an element and it hasn't loaded yet which gives me null value and nothing works. So if i could just wait till the function that i called in `anotherFunction` gets executed completely then it would be easier for me to deal with it. I've seen `promises` if I'm not wrong helps in making code synchronous (Not able to understand how to implement that). Help me out!

Comment: Please read the documentation. You even know the word you are looking for. Be very careful what ajax-calls you do synchronous though, and consider doing it asynchronous with a success function instead. This doesn't stop the rest of your javascript from running.

Comment: Yes the ajax call is loading the interface successfully. But i'm trying to access the element loaded by that ajax call by `getElementById` which works great on firefox but in chrome it yields a null value.

Comment: I would need to see code to try to figure out what might go wrong. @Guilherme's answer should work fine if you move all code dependant on the ajax-call in that success function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to use [`deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) objects

```
function doAjaxStuff(){
  return $.ajax(...);
}


function anotherFunction() {
    $.when(doAjaxStuff()).then(function(){
       // other code to run after ajax call
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried implementing in first place. Didn't had enough luck to get it right. Thanks, that finally works now and it makes perfect sense :)

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a callback function as argument to `doAjaxStuff` and call it when your ajax request is done.

```
function doAjaxStuff(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        success: function(data) {
            // do some stuff with data
            callback(data);
        }
    });
}

function anotherFunction() {
    doAjaxStuff(function(data) {
        alert(data);
    })
}
```

In JavaScript, functions are also objects, which means they can be passed as argument to another function as well as you can do with any other value. So in this case we have a parameter called `callback` in the function `doAjaxStuff`. When the ajax request is complete, we can call this function that was passed as argument.

Comment: @Cruze I added some more explanation at the end of the post, maybe it can clarify a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
      $.ajax({
        url:"demo_test.txt",
        async:false,
        success:function(result){
        }
     });
```

> all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false

REFERENCE

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I don't need synchronous request to server but i need to get that ajax part done and only after that proceed to the next code after the function call.

Comment: I'd suggest not to use this as synchronous ajax requests block the user interface while there is no response from the server.

Comment: I just want that the call to `doAjaxStuff` finishes first and then it should proceed with the code that is below the call.

Comment: @Cruze - what you're describing is exactly what this answer will do - but its not a good idea for the reasons stated. The best option is as described in the other answer.